# C# HttpService JSON Serialization causes Connection Reset when using List in custom Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, serialization, httpservice

**NOTE: I've re-edited this entire post to give the simplest version I can.**

I'm creating a simple web service that just returns data, but like most JSON data, there can be a hierarchy of different types. Here is a brief example of the code:

```
using MyData = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;

   [ServiceContract()]
    public interface IJSONReceiver
    {
        [OperationContract()]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "TestData",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        MyData TestData();
    }

    [ServiceBehaviorAttribute(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class JSONReceiver : IJSONReceiver
    {
        private Random rndm = new Random();

        MyData IJSONReceiver.TestData()
        {
            MyData rval = new MyData(); // MyDictionary();
            string[] shapes = { "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" };
            rval["line1"] = "Line One";
            rval["line2"] = "Line Two";
            rval["line3"] = "Line Three";
            rval["shape"] = shapes[rndm.Next(shapes.Length)];
            List<string> test = new List<string>();
            foreach(string s in shapes)
            {
                test.Add(s);
            }
            rval["shapes"] = test; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            return rval;
        }
}
```

As written above, when I try to access this from an external client (I'm using Postman for testing), or even from any browser, I get a Connection Reset error. I'm running this in debug mode in VS, there are no exceptions thrown, it just fails.

HOWEVER, if I comment out the problematic line (just before the return), it properly returns the JSON serialized data:

```
[
    {
        "Key": "line1",
        "Value": "Line One"
    },
    {
        "Key": "line2",
        "Value": "Line Two"
    },
    {
        "Key": "line3",
        "Value": "Line Three"
    },
    {
        "Key": "shape",
        "Value": "Triangle"
    }
]
```

Now, I could force a different serializer - if I use the JavaScriptSerializer, the string it creates is correct, but then WebInvoke is doing another implicit serialization, which means the client would need to deserialize twice to the get the data correctly. That's very inelegant. If I could tell WebInvoke to NOT serialize (like WebMessageFormat.Bare, but it doesn't exist), it could also work.

Ultimately I feel like I need to somehow tell it to recurse through sub-objects, but I don't know how to do it, or if that's even the problem. It seems weird that a serialization issue would cause a connection reset, and not an exception.

In case it matters, here is the class to start/stop the service:

```
class HTTPService
{
    private WebServiceHost host = null;
    private ServiceEndpoint endpoint = null;
    private Logger logger = Logger.GetInstance;

    public Boolean StartService(
        ref JSONReceiver receiver,
        string URI)
    {
        Boolean rval = false;
        if (URI != null)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(URI);
            receiver = new JSONReceiver();
            host = new WebServiceHost(receiver, uri);
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IJSONReceiver), binding, "");
            try
            {
                host.Open();
                logger.Log(
                    String.Format("Started running on {0}", URI),
                    MyLog.LogLevels.Debugging);
                rval = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.Log(
                    String.Format("HTTPService: {0}", e.Message),
                    MyLog.LogLevels.Errors);
            }
        }
        return rval;
    }

    public void StopService()
    {
        if(host != null)
        {
            try
            {
                host.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignore errors on close
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your description looks very complex. can you please add in short what exactly your problem is

Comment: Can you include the actual code that calls HttpService?

Comment: @viveknuna When I try to serialize a Dictionary<string, object> and object is a List, something fails in the HttpService, causing connection reset error, whether it's the serialization or something else. If all the objects in the Dictionary are basic objects, like strings, it serializes and returns the JSON correctly.

Comment: @Jahmic Sorry, to be clear I'm using WebServiceHost - I've added the code that starts/stops the service. The service is being called, externally, by Postman. https://www.postman.com/ It lets you, among other things, test your web based APIs.

Comment: @viveknuna I've prepended my post with what I hope is a shorter, clearer version of the problem.

Comment: @Fhaab  you can use try catch block to see the exception details. You can use the jsonutils.com to see the expected class for your json and compare with your class.

Comment: @viveknuna There's no exception - if there was an exception, I could track down the error. I'm just going to re-edit my whole post with a shorter version. jsonutils doesn't help with a dictionary of string to object mappings, where object could be anything (serializable).